# Sliding window with burn-in elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sliding-window

I have a Python list. Here is an example:

```
seq = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Now I would like to iterate over the list with a window. For example, with a window of size 3 I can do it as follows:

```
window_size = 3
for i in range(len(seq) - window_size + 1):
    print(seq[i: i + window_size])
```

This would result in the following output:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
```

Now, I would like to also include the burn-in phase, i.e. lists with less than window_size elements. The output should be as follows:

```
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
```

How can my code be extended to do this most efficiently (also for bigger lists and bigger window_size)?

Comment: Do you not need `[4, 5]` and `[5]`?

Comment: @Zero No, these two lists are not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are good answers already to this question, but just wanted to share another method using only 1 loop to do the same.

```
window_size = 3
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for x in range(1, len(arr)+1):
    if x < window_size:
        print(arr[:x])
    
    else:
        print(arr[x-window_size:x])
```

Output:

```
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just append each value in the input list to a new list. If the new list's size exceeds that of the window size, remove the first element.

For example:

```
seq = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

WINDOW_SIZE = 3

window = []

for v in seq:
    window.append(v)
    if len(window) > WINDOW_SIZE:
        window = window[1:] # or window.pop(0)
    print(window)
```

**Output:**

```
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 6]
[5, 6, 7]
[6, 7, 8]
[7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/collections.html#collections.deque) and generalize this to a generator function:

```
from collections import deque


def windowed(seq, window_size):
    window = deque(maxlen=window_size)
    for item in seq:
        window.append(item)
        yield tuple(window)


for win in windowed([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3):
    print(win)
```

This outputs

```
(0,)
(0, 1)
(0, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 3)
(2, 3, 4)
(3, 4, 5)
```

The generator function is handy in that it also works for collections you can't slice (and even other generators):

```
import random
import time
import itertools

def generate_random_numbers_slowly():
    while True:
        yield random.randint(0, 100)
        time.sleep(0.1)


for win in windowed(itertools.islice(generate_random_numbers_slowly(), 10), 3):
    print(win)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by simply introducing another loop that iterates from 1 to the window_size

```
seq = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for window_size in range(1, len(seq)):
    for i in range(len(seq) - window_size + 1):
        print(seq[i: i + window_size])

for i in range(len(seq)):
    print(seq[i: i + window_size])
```